# Finding recurence function and math expression from a given code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was given a task to analyze a code to find the math expression, recurrence function of the code, and time complexity.

The code:

```
int M(int B[],int l,int r)
{
    if(l == r) return (B[l]>0)?B[l]:0;
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    int mls = M(B,l,m);
    int mrs = M(B,m+1,r);
    int mlbs = 0, lbs = 0;
    for(int i = m;i >= l;i--){
        lbs += B[i]; 
        if(lbs > mlbs) mlbs = lbs;
    }
    int mrbs = 0, rbs =0;
    for(int j = m+1;j <= r;j++){   
        rbs += B[j];                 
        if(rbs > mrbs) mrbs = rbs;
    }                              
    return Max3(mls,mrs,mlbs+mrbs);
}
```

The question:

```
Then find
(a) Math expression of the code
(b) Recurrence Function of the code
(c) Time complexity of the code using one of the methods discussed. (I have learn master theorem, recurrence tree, and subtitution)
```

So far, I have analyzed the operation on the code below

```
// T(n)
int M(int B[],int l,int r)
{
    if(l == r) return (B[l]>0)?B[l]:0;     // 1, because the comparation in the return
                                           //    will be rarely occur
    int m = (l+r)/2;                       // 3
    int mls = M(B,l,m);                    // T(n / 2) \
                                           //           -> 2T(n/2)
    int mrs = M(B,m+1,r);                  // T(n / 2) /
    int mlbs = 0, lbs = 0;                 // 2
    for(int i = m;i >= l;i--){             // loop -> n / 2
        lbs += B[i];                       //   1
        if(lbs > mlbs) mlbs = lbs;         //   1, if the element on the B is negative, then it
                                           //      produce a random pattern so we can ignore it
    }                                      // end loop
    int mrbs = 0, rbs =0;                  // 2
    for(int j = m+1;j <= r;j++){           // loop -> n / 2
        rbs += B[j];                       //   1
        if(rbs > mrbs) mrbs = rbs;         //   1, if the element on the B is negative, then it
                                           //      produce a random pattern so we can ignore it
    }                                      // end loop
    return Max3(mls,mrs,mlbs+mrbs);        // 3, Max3 would be O(2)
}
```

The function will be

```
T(n) = 1 + 3 + T(n/2) + T(n/2) + 2 + 2 * (n/2) + 2 + (n/2) * (2 + 1) + 2 + 2 * (n/2) + 2 + (n/2) * (2 + 1) + 3
Then,
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + 3n + 15
```

Using master theorem, we can get the time complexity of the function is `n log n`.

**My question**

Am I doing it correctly if mine is incorrect and if possible explain the problem? And how I can get the recurrence function or math expression (I still confuse to distinguish both of them)?